# error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Genexus ev1

Tags: c#, genexus, asp

Buenas tardes estoy desarrollando una aplicacion con **GeneXus X evolution 1** en ambiente web(.NET) pero al crear un web panel , Web Component o simplement con modificar algo en un event e intentar guardar o compilar me sale:

> "error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

no necesariamente tengo que modificar algo simplemente con que no tenga nada y solo lo intente guardar. Espero y me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Ese error es en el 99% de los casos porque estas intentado acceder a un método de un objeto que no esta inicializado (es null). Como no pones nada de codigo, es dificil ayudarte mas,pero te doy un ejemplo de codigo que lanzaria esta excepcion:

```
string cadena = null;
cadena.ToUpper();
```

Como ves, al intentar acceder al metodo `ToUpper` del `cadena` y no estar este inicializado, se lanza la excepcion.

Si nos pones algo de código relevante te podremos ayudar mas.